# Error message when importing spreadsheet data in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

When I am importing spreadsheet data (A to N columns, 200++ rows) into Access 2013 web app, for the last step of "Import Spreadsheet Wizard", when I clicked "Finish", I received this error message

> "Method "ExecuteTempImexSpec" of object '_WizHook' failed."

Can anyone please shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The file is likely open in another window.

Comment: Hi, do you mean that the Excel file is left open?

Comment: But I had closed the Excel file before I import the spreadsheet data into Access. What's happening here??

Comment: Generally speaking, that should have done it.  As it didn't we need to know more of the variables.  Has this worked before? Have you necessary permissions to the web app? Does the data actually line up correctly or has something changed in the Excel source not reflected properly in the web app?  How many actual columns are there?  Access has a 256 limit.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resaving the .csv file as an .xlsx file and tried again and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just has this error,
my assumption is (changing it actually fixed it but I didn't undo and check again if it errors out) that

MS access checks the data type based on the first few records, I had a row with headers names sorted wrong much further in the sheet (i combined a few sheets), I deleted the header row and it worked fine